# Present my all videos from a certain YouTube channel

Tags: video

I would like to make a page **on my site** that shows an embedded video player for **each** video in a certain YouTube channel.  (I don't want to just link to YouTube's page for that channel)  Preferably I would like some control over presentation.  What's the best way to do this?  If server programming is necessary, I would be most comfortable with a Perl solution but would be open to PHP, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution... write a Perl script using this module:

http://search.cpan.org/~ebosrup/RSS-Parser-Lite-0.10/lib/XML/RSS/Parser/Lite.pm

to parse the RSS feeds described here:

http://www.youtube.com/rssls

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check -> http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_audience.html

For me there is no need from server side support, haven`t go deep in the API but I think the JavaScript will be enough for you.